# Problem of downloading an app

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

When i open the app store of my iPhone 4 and then search for an app or game say clash of clans, then the downloading starts in the app store but when i go back to the home screen the game's or the app's icon doesn't come there. Even after the game is downloaded in the app store then also its icon does not come on home screen. In the app store even the open button comes after downloading is finished but nothing opens after clicking on it. Please help!!

Comment: I don’t know if there is a concept of multiple screens on iPhone 4. All new apps are shown on second screen in iOS 12. What version are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

### Have you already tried to turn it OFF and ON again?

If so, you may want to sign out of your Apple ID on the App Store and then sign back in.

If all this didn't fix the issue, you may want to contact Apple via their Support going on their dedicated Support [page](https://getsupport.apple.com/) and choosing the following:

iTunes and Apple Music > iTunes Store > Connection and Download > Incomplete downloads from the iTunes Store > Finally, contact Apple Support via Email.

**P.S**. **Update**: chat option should also be available now.